# Swift "Protocol type 'AnyObject' cannot be instantiated" error while returning to AnyObject

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I am trying to write the following Java code on Swift.

```
public static double eval(final String str) {
    return new Object() {
        int pos = -1, ch; // these fields are used across all the methods

        void nextChar() {
             // ...
        }

        boolean eat(int charToEat) {
            // ...
            // calls nextChar somewhere
        }

        double parse() {
            // ...
            // calls nextChar and parseExpression somewhere
        }

        double parseExpression() {
            // ...
            // calls parseTerm somewhere
        }

        double parseTerm() {
            // ...
            // calls parseFactor somewhere
        }

        double parseFactor() {
            // ...
            // recursively calls parseFactor and parseExpression somewhere
        }
    }.parse();
}
```

I encountered the problem on Swift telling that "Protocol type 'AnyObject' cannot be instantiated". My Swift code is below. How can I achieve this conversion? I mean, how can I return a function to anyobject on Swift?

```
func eval(str: String) -> Double {
    return AnyObject {             //Here it says "Protocol type 'AnyObject' cannot be instantiated"
       ...
       func parse() -> Double {
           ...
       }
    }.parse()
}
```

I wrote briefly above in order to be clear, but as I see the answers, it will be better to post the whole code. The swift code is provided below. I am working on the calcultor code provided by Boann on url https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227947/12698480

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question you posted a couple of days ago, instead of posting some java code as the answer can't you explain in words what your function is supposed to do, what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I can provide a more helpful answer if you can show what code the first `....... (some code)` contains.

Comment: @Sweeper I added the whole code on my first post, can you look now?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I added the whole code on my post, can you look now?

Comment: See the updated answer. I've edited your question to include the minimum amount of information that your question needs, so as not to make it too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have translated the Java code too literally. We should first understand what the Java code does, and why the author has written it like that.

What the Java code is doing, is creating a class "inline", and calling one of its methods immediately. The class has many methods and state, and the methods mutates the state and call each other recursively. IMO, it should really be moved into a named class, but the author might have thought that this is the only place where it will be used, so they did it "inline".

You can directly nest functions in Swift, so you can just ignore the `new Object` part and directly do:

```
func eval(str: String) -> Double {
    var pos = -1
    var ch = -1

    func nextChar() {
         // ...
    }

    func eat(charToEat: Int) -> Bool {
        // ...
    }

    func parse() -> Double {
        // ...
    }

    func parseExpression() -> Double {
        // ...
    }

    func parseTerm() -> Double {
        // ...
    }

    func parseFactor() -> Double {
        // ...
    }
    
    return parse()
}
```

However, when it's this many methods, and this complex, I would just make a class/struct instead:

```
struct Parser {
    var str: String
    // put everything declared in eval here
}
```

In `eval`, do:

```
Parser(str: str).parse()
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for your quick and step by step very clear to understand help, I really appreciate! Now I will try all of your suggestions now, I hope I achieve since I'm a little new:)

Comment: "IMO, it should really be moved into a named class" Yes, I agree, but my rationale was I was trying to keep it self-contained so it was easy to copy-paste and reuse.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states `AnyObject` is a protocol/typealias (called interface in Java) rather than a concrete type. This means you can't instantiate it directly because the compiler doesn't know what the actual type would be.
Consider the following example:

```swift
protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get }
    var height: Double { get }
}
```

And then you add some different animal types that could potentially do some custom logic for whatever reason:

```swift
struct Dog: Animal {
    let name: String
    let height: Double
}

struct Cat: Animal {
    let name: String
    let height: Double
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```swift
var myPet: Animal?
myPet = Cat(name: "Scratchy", height: 20.2)
myPet = Dog(name: "Barky", height: 53.8)
```

This compiles correctly because you're not trying to instantiate an object of type `Animal` directly but are rather creating a 'placeholder'. You can now assign any object to it that conforms to `Animal`